# Camera2 - problem setting AE reigon, AF region AWB region

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am new to camera2 and so far I have implemented most of the things in Camera2 but my requirements state that I should have the focus in the middle, exposure and white balance should be calculated based on the middle part.

To calculate the middle region, I used this

```kotlin
fun getRegion() : MeteringRectangle {
    val sensorRect: Rect = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE)!!
    val sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION)!!

    val regionWidth = 200
    val regionHeight = 200
    var regionLeft: Int = (sensorRect.width() - regionWidth) / 2
    var regionTop: Int = (sensorRect.height() - regionHeight) / 2

    if (sensorOrientation == 90 || sensorOrientation == 270) {
        val temp = regionLeft
        regionLeft = regionTop
        regionTop = temp
    }

    return MeteringRectangle(
        regionLeft,
        regionTop,
        regionWidth,
        regionHeight,
        MeteringRectangle.METERING_WEIGHT_MAX - 1
    )
}
```

I think this is giving a promising result but since I am a beginner I can't really understand the whole process that this API do, I tried to set regions like this, but I had no positive outcome, I get blur on the preview

```kotlin
private fun createPreviewRequest() {
    val previewSurface = Surface(viewFinder.surfaceTexture)

    repeatingRequest = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
    repeatingRequest.addTarget(previewSurface)
    val matArr = getRegion()

    repeatingRequest.apply {
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_REGIONS, arrayOf(matArr))
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, arrayOf(matArr))
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_REGIONS, arrayOf(matArr))
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO)
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO)
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)
        set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
    }

    cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(repeatingRequest.build(), captureCallBack, cameraHandler)
}
```

What could be the process to implement my requirements?

Note: For simplicity, I didn't put any check on whether the device support AE, AF, AWB region or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2):

- You need to set the autofocus and auto-exposure region to the area that's been tapped by the user, which you can accomplish using the [`CONTROL_AF_REGIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AF_REGIONS) and [`CONTROL_AE_REGIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AE_REGIONS) keys. These units need to be translated from your UI touch coordinates to the active array coordinates of the sensor.
  After you have calculated the region, you should set the AF mode to `AUTO`, then trigger AF and wait for [`CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED) to take a picture that's in focus. If you want to return to normal operation after a while, or if the user cancels the touch to focus, you should switch the AF mode back to [`CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE).
  See "[Implement Tap to Focus in Camera2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33151244/6309)"
- Regarding exposure control, you can manually set the exposure time and ISO by using the [`SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME) and [`SENSOR_SENSITIVITY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#SENSOR_SENSITIVITY) keys respectively. For example, setting the exposure time to 500000000L will result in an exposure time of 0.5 seconds, and setting the `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` to 400 will result in an ISO of 400.

For a current (2023) example, I would recommend taking a look at [`android/camera-samples/Camera2Extensions`, class `java/com/example/android/camera2/extensions/fragments/CameraFragment.kt`](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/cce92313279754d08a77ee6c35ad8126e25e9245/Camera2Extensions/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/extensions/fragments/CameraFragment.kt), which has focus-related function.

For instance:

```java
/**
 * Translates a touch event relative to the preview surface to a region relative to the sensor.
 * Note: This operation does not account for zoom / crop and should be handled otherwise the touch
 * point won't correctly map to the sensor.
 */
private fun meteringRectangle(event: MotionEvent): MeteringRectangle {
val sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION)!!
val sensorSize = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE)!!

val halfMeteringRectWidth = (METERING_RECTANGLE_SIZE * sensorSize.width()) / 2
val halfMeteringRectHeight = (METERING_RECTANGLE_SIZE * sensorSize.height()) / 2

// Normalize the [x,y] touch point in the view port to values in the range of [0,1]
val normalizedPoint = floatArrayOf(event.x / previewSize.height, event.y / previewSize.width)

// Scale and rotate the normalized point such that it maps to the sensor region
Matrix().apply {
    postRotate(-sensorOrientation.toFloat(), 0.5f, 0.5f)
    postScale(sensorSize.width().toFloat(), sensorSize.height().toFloat())
    mapPoints(normalizedPoint)
}

val meteringRegion = Rect(
    (normalizedPoint[0] - halfMeteringRectWidth).toInt().coerceIn(0, sensorSize.width()),
    (normalizedPoint[1] - halfMeteringRectHeight).toInt().coerceIn(0, sensorSize.height()),
    (normalizedPoint[0] + halfMeteringRectWidth).toInt().coerceIn(0, sensorSize.width()),
    (normalizedPoint[1] + halfMeteringRectHeight).toInt().coerceIn(0, sensorSize.height())
)

return MeteringRectangle(meteringRegion, MeteringRectangle.METERING_WEIGHT_MAX)
}

private fun startAutoFocus(meteringRectangle: MeteringRectangle) {
submitRequest(
    CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW,
    previewSurface,
    false,
    ) { request ->
        request.apply {
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, arrayOf(meteringRectangle))
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO)
        set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START)
        setTag(AUTO_FOCUS_TAG)
        }
    }
}
```